# Best Way To Fill Screen With Grid of Images

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablelayout, stretch

I'm writing an Android app in java that I want to be able to use across all phone screen sizes and resolutions.  I need to create a 4x4 array of images (all square and equal in size).  I want the images to expand such that they're width is basically the screen width divided by 4.

I first tried a `RelativeLayout`, but can't figure it out.  I figure `TableLayout` is probably the way to go, but if I just stretch columns, that won't necessarily stretch the images within the cells, right?  I need the images to stretch, not just the columns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/GridLayout.java) Layout called GridLayout by Romain Guy. You simply addview() your imageviews .Enjoy